# How to send Json with different values?

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a JSON, for example:

```
{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"car":"Ford"
}
```

I would like to send this same JSON many times, but every time the age value is different, for example

```
"age":31, then "age":32 and so on...
```

How can I do that?

Comment: value is increment or random or other? every X interval or in different flows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use variable as age,

For example for incremented value: add `Config Element -> Counter` with Reference Name `age` Start `30`, Increment `1`.

You JSON will be with `${age}`: 
    { "name":"John", "age":${age}, "car":"Ford" }

And then just execute `Thread Group` with `Loop Count` as 5 and the request will submitted with increasing age value.